# Android sqlite foreign key references multiple row

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two tables A and B.
In table A, it contains two cols, A1,A2 where A1 is primary key
In table B, one of the column, let says B2, store an array of value in col A1
I want to reference every element in this array to col A1 in table A. Is this possbile

For example,
table A
ID|name|value
1|OTZ|10
2|hello world 10
3|apple|2
4|orange|5

table B
id|array
1|1,2
2|3,4
3|1,4

How can I reference those value in col array to table A?

Comment: so your primary key in A is the TEXTUAL value?! and you want to save those PKS in table B as an array?... please dont - there are some cases where you want to break the ACID rules (performance over data integrety) - this seems to be not the case here.

Comment: Ok, I can add one more column table A for primary key. But then how can I reference it in table B?

Comment: well, UML wise speaking you want to store a n:m connection between table A and B - this is usually done with an table A_B storing both primary key from A and B as an combined primary key. So you can save every possible combination of As and Bs

Comment: Would you mine answering my question and then I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for, a short answer - this is how you solve a "many to many" relation between two tables.
Many to Many can also mean, that one entry in Table A has no connection to TABLE B at all, or it has hundres (and vice verca)

If you got

```
TABLE A
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
a_description TEXT NOT NULL

TABLE B
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
b_description TEXT NOT NULL
```

if you want to save a relation between those two, you will need a mapping-table, most of the time called TABLEA2B (or something like that) which holds at minimum the both primary key of those tables as a combined primary key (so that the same combination is not allowed twice)

```
TABLE A2B
A_id INT,
B_id INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`A_id`, `B_id`)
CONSTRAINT...
```

A article about that with an UML diagram and complete (working) SQL Example codes can be found here: http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/